# Python create list of tuples of strings by splitting from regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

Supose I've got this two strings:

```
s1 = 'hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help (1345-today is wednesday)'
s2 = 'hello again, this is a (bit-more complicated), string (67890123 - tomorrow is thursday)'
```

I want to use regex to match the pattern `(number-words)` and then split the strings to get a list of tuples:

```
final = [('hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help', '1345-today is wednesday'),
         ('hello again, this is a (bit-more complicated), string', '67890123 - tomorrow is thursday')]
```

I tried with `\([0-9]+-(.*?)\)` but without success.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea to get a workaround?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Try `list(filter(None, re.split(r'\s*(?=\([0-9]+\s*-\s*[a-zA-Z])', s1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex in `findall`:

```
>>> regx = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\s*\((\d+\s*-\s*\w+[^)]*)\)')
>>> arr = ['hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help (1345-today is wednesday)', 'hello again, this is a (bit-more complicated), string (67890123 - tomorrow is thursday)']
>>> for el in arr:
...     regx.findall(el)
...
[('hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help', '1345-today is wednesday')]
[('hello again, this is a (bit-more complicated), string', '67890123 - tomorrow is thursday')]
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^(.*?)`: Match 0 or more characters at the start in group #1
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `\((\d+\s*-\s*\w+[^)]*)\)`: Match `(<number>-word ..)` string and capture what is inside brackets in capture group #2

---

**Alternatively**, you may use this regex in `split`:

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?<!\s)\s*(?=\((\d+\s*-\s*\w+[^)]*)\))')
>>> for el in arr:
...     reg.split(el)[:-1]
...
['hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help', '1345-today is wednesday']
['hello again, this is a (bit-more complicated), string', '67890123 - tomorrow is thursday']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iggwM5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\s)`: If we don't have a whitespace at previous position
- `\s*`: Match 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=\((\d+\s*-\s*\w+[^)]*)\))`: Lookahead to assert a string ahead of us which is `(<number>-word ..)`. Note that we are using a capture group to get string inside `(...)` in the result of `split`.

Comment: And how for just get the string inside (...) in the result of split?

Comment: You want to get rid of `'hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help'` or `(1345-today is wednesday)` ?

Comment: I want to get a tuple of `('hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help', '1345-today is wednesday')` and the <number-word> pattern without parentheses. And no, no text after (number-word) pattern

Comment: Glad it worked. I have added a `findall` solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might nudge you in the right direction:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(.*) \((.+?)\)$', s1)
[('hello 4, this is stackoverflow, looking for help', '1345-today is wednesday')]
```